# Time is not Count continuously in when app is lock in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, time, countdowntimer

How can I count the time when the app is locked because I need to navigate to the screen after the second is over can anyone help me with this task. Because I am trying to background fetch its works in debug mode but it's not working in Ios build also when the timer is complete to count then play music and navigate the page

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_countdown_timer/index.dart';
import 'package:meditation_app/constant/strings.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

import '../../constant/colors.dart';
import '../../constant/image.dart';
import '../../constant/preferences_key.dart';
import '../streak_screen/streak_screen.dart';

class CountdownPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int setTimerValue;
  CountdownPage({required this.setTimerValue});
  @override
  _CountdownPageState createState() => _CountdownPageState();
}

class _CountdownPageState extends State<CountdownPage> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  late AudioCache audioCache;
  late Map<String, dynamic> prefData;
  bool isRunning = false;

  CountdownController? countdownController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    countdownController = CountdownController(
        duration: Duration(minutes: widget.setTimerValue),
        onEnd: () {
          countdownController?.dispose();
          audioCache.play("timer_song.mp3");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageTransition(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              type: PageTransitionType.fade,
              child: StreakScreen(
                streakCount: prefData['data']['STRIKE'],
                subtitleText: prefData['meditationData']['TEXT'],
                userID: prefData['data']['USER_ID'],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
    countdownController?.start();
    isRunning = true;
    var data = preferences.getString(Keys.userReponse);
    prefData = jsonDecode(data!);

    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    countdownController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
            Column(
              children: [
                Countdown(
                    countdownController: countdownController!,
                    builder: (_, Duration time) {
                      return Text(
                        time.toString().substring(2, 7),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.09,
                          color: Colours.whiteColor,
                          fontFamily: 'FuturaBookFont',
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                ),
                beginButton(),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0425),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                  backButton(context),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.008),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget beginButton() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
        if (!countdownController!.isRunning) {
          countdownController?.start();
          setState(() {
            isRunning = true;
          });
        } else {
          countdownController?.stop();
          setState(() {
            isRunning = false;
          });
        }
      },
      child: Image.asset(
        !isRunning ? ConstImages.playImage : ConstImages.pauseImage,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.085,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget backButton(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
        countdownController?.dispose();

        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageTransition(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            type: PageTransitionType.fade,
            child: StreakScreen(
              streakCount: prefData['data']['STRIKE'],
              subtitleText: prefData['meditationData']['TEXT'],
              userID: prefData['data']['USER_ID'],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Text(
        Strings.finishButtonTExt,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colours.whiteColor,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontFamily: 'FuturaMediumBT',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          letterSpacing: 0.78,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Counting is never a reliable approach.  Calculate the `Date` that represents the end time and then use a repeating timer to check if "now" is after that date.

Comment: when I set 5 min after that then counter can start to count but when I lock my phone counter is stopped but when I unlock my phone counter starts again count so how can I count time when I lock my phone

Comment: Don't count time.   You can't. Work out what time it will be 5 minutes from the start and store that in a variable. Then have a timer that fires every second and compare to see if it now after the end time.  If it is, take whatever action is required.   If the phone is locked for 5 minutes or an hour or more, as soon as the app returns to the foreground you will see that the deadline has passed at take the action

Comment: could you please share code here

Comment: Sorry, I can't write Dart. This article may help https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f It describes the problem and how to use a `Date` to measure elapsed time.  You can use a similar approach to determine if you are past a deadline

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen when the screen is locked and unlocked after your countdown expires? Lets say you have a 3 minute countdown, I close my phone and put it aside, what should happen after 3 minutes, what should happen when I open my phone 10 minutes later?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on a timer firing accurately when an app is suspended or the device is asleep.

The solution is to calculate your required deadline and then periodically check if it has passed.  The check will not happen while your app is suspended or the device is asleep, but it doesn't matter.  As soon as your app resumes it can check if the deadline has passed and take the required action.

I'm afraid I can't help you with Dart code, but here is some pseudo-code that describes the approach

```
let deadline = Date()+300 // Deadline is 300 seconds from now
timer.every(1) {          // Check every second
   if Date() > deadline {
       TakeAction()       // Take action if the deadline is earlier than now
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need to in Dart code